# Run a script on a failed screen unlock attempt

Tags: elementary-os, d-bus, screen-lock

I want to run a script in Python to detect when a user tries to unlock the screen, but fails.

I use elementary OS Freya and light-lock. I tried it with dbus, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

I'm trying this:

```
dbus-monitor "type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.login1.Session'"
```

This is the result:

```
signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> dest=:1.170 serial=2 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameAcquired
string ":1.170"
```

I don't know what to make of this. Because after that, the terminal stays quiet and doesn't show anything.

Comment: Do you mean when someone *logs in*, or when someone *unlocks the screen*? Do you want to run this when a user is typing their username/password, or only if the login/password is accepted?

Comment: I mean when a password don't match.

Comment: Oh, that was really not clear in your original post. On the login screen, or on a screen unlock? And why are you listening to dbus events? Are you trying to do this without having root access? That's not going to work.

Comment: Ups!, Sorry about that D:,  Is in the login screen, Why? Well... I'm trying to create a logging error detector for use in an application. And yes, I'am trying to do this only a simple user.
In this question http://superuser.com/questions/662974/logging-lock-screen-events apparently can do it

Comment: Once again: *lock screen*, or *login screen*? Those are completely different questions.

Comment: Ok, maybe I don't know differentiate one and other, if I think of it, is the **lock screen** 
See this image: http://ubuntuportal.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Elementary-OS-Freya-Lock-and-login-screen.jpg
Thanks for your help @Gilles

Comment: does (or could, with some options set) some log file show anything when it happens? you could have a deamon script/program parse the log and react

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks for yor reply, so, Can I get the event unlock? How is it? Is possible to detect the enter key?

Comment: You probably need to approach the other way, the lock ask libpam, and libpam logs *everything*.

Comment: @Braiam you talking about like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286321/pam-authentication-in-python-without-root-privileges

Comment: No. libpam has a log file that logs every failed and successful login attempt. Check out the man pages.

Comment: Ok, thanks to everybody. I need time to testing. See ya!